# How to use [(ng-model)] when using Renderer2 in Anguar5

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

Below is my code to create input box using Renderer2 DOM Creation. For this I need to add `[(ng-Model)`] using renderer. What will be the syntax to add directives?

**Something like this:**

```
renderer.setAttribute("[ng-Model]",name)
let input = this.renderer.createElement('input');
        input.type = typeof res[key];
        input.placeholder = `Search By ${key}`;
        input.id = `SearchField0${key}`;
        this.renderer.setAttribute(input, "class", "SearchField search_1");
        this.renderer.listen(input, 'input', () => { this.getValFilter();});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to set up any Angular directive like that. Renderer2 just adds the element to DOM, but you will have no way of wiring it up with Angular logics (e.g. directives).

The alternatives would be to

- add the dynamic input fields in the template and use `ngModel` on them or
- use reactive forms to dynamically set them up from your TS class.